# how to make equal height cards which are in two different columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I have two Bootstrap columns with cards in them. I want the cards inside the columns to grow or increase in height equally based on the content inside. In my case, I want 'card-one' and 'card-three' to share equal heights, and 'card-two' and 'card-four' to share equal heights. I've tried the above, but I can't control 'card-one' and 'card-three' to share equal heights as they are in different columns."

Here's the corrected codepen

```js
//document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "6vw";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.one {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.three {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.four {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container align-items-stretch">
  <div class="card w-100 h-100">
    <div class="card-body w-100 h-100 d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="row align-items-stretch flex-grow-1">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card w-100 h-100">
            <div class="card-header w-100">
              header
            </div>
            <div class="card-body w-100  mt-4">
              <div class="card border w-100 shadow card-one">
                <div class="card-body w-100">
                  <label class="one">1</label> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, id cupiditate repudiandae ab exercitationem nesciunt? Provident, voluptatum! Distinctio atque exercitationem pariatur voluptatum fuga dolorem,
                  earum dolores tenetur eveniet placeat dolore!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card border w-100 shadow mt-4 card-two">
                <div class="card-body w-100">
                  <label class="two">2</label> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, id cupiditate repudiandae ab exercitationem nesciunt? Provident, voluptatum! Distinctio atque exercitationem pariatur voluptatum fuga dolorem,
                  earum dolores tenetur eveniet placeat dolore!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card w-100 h-100">
            <div class="card-header w-100">
              header
            </div>
            <div class="card-body w-100  mt-4">
              <div class="card border w-100 shadow card-three">
                <div class="card-body w-100">
                  <label class="three">3</label> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, id cupiditate repudiandae ab exercitationem nesciunt? Provident, voluptatum! Distinctio atque exercitationem pariatur voluptatum fuga dolorem,
                  earum dolores tenetur eveniet placeat dolore!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card border w-100 shadow mt-4 card-four">
                <div class="card-body w-100">
                  <label class="four">4</label> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia, id cupiditate repudiandae ab exercitationem nesciunt? Provident, voluptatum! Distinctio atque exercitationem pariatur voluptatum fuga dolorem,
                  earum dolores tenetur eveniet placeat dolore!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Seems they are all the same height